# Installed 13.10, continuous internet problems

Tags: wireless, 13.10, internet, connection

I installed 13.10 on my Toshiba Sattelite A-150, and since, I have been having internet issues. I know that it's the computer, because no other computer in the house has this problem. It won't load webpages, or maintain connections to servers, like google servers. If I want to load a webpage, i have to turn off my WiFi and turn it back on. Any questions?

Comment: Could you add information to your networking hardware and configuration? `ifconfig -a` Interesting is `eth0` and `wlan0`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your wifi chipset is not supported by standard ubuntu driver.
Use google to find your wifi chipset and download proprietary drivers.